# Text selection not clears when click on `img` source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container, and it has children within. one of the children has the `text` in it. another has the `img` in it.

the problem is, when user select the `text` (using mouse, just like selecting text in word doc etc), assume that, the user click on the image source (which is occupied the parent), the `text` not clearning.

the text keeps `selection` up to i click out of `img` source. how to fix this issue.

I require, even if the user clicks on `img` the selection need to cleared.

```js
$('.container').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    //window.getSelection().empty(); i can't use this.
    console.log(target); //getting img.
});
```

```css
.container{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.imageHolder{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.textHolder {
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageHolder"><img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/599431/127612211/stock-photo-green-apple-isolated-on-white-background-127612211.jpg" width=300 height=150></div>
    <div class="textHolder">some text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Can any one help me to solve this? possibly **I would like to avoid `js` function, in case if there is a solution in `css` or `html`.**

In case if i use this `js` function, i am not able to select the `text` at all..

```
if (window.getSelection) window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    else if (document.selection) document.selection.empty();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bawjvL98/1/)

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/bawjvL98/2/

Comment: I am not get any result here..? what you have updated?

Comment: I commented your JS Code.Now if you check your fiddle , I guess JS Code cause issue.

Comment: no, you are wrong. the `js` not at all connected with this process. still no change...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the Following.

```js
$('.container').on('click', function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    //window.getSelection().empty(); i can't use this.
    //console.log(target); //getting img.
  var txt=$(this).find(".textHolder");
  if(target[0].tagName === 'IMG')
    {
      
      txt.addClass('noselect');
      txt.attr('unselectable','on');
      
            
    }else{
      txt.removeClass('noselect');
      txt.attr('unselectable','off');
    }
});

$('.container .textHolder').on('mousedown',function(){
  $(this).removeClass('noselect');
  $(this).attr('unselectable','off');
});
```

```css
.container{
    border:1px solid green;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
}
.imageHolder{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

.textHolder {
    position:absolute;
}

.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="imageHolder"><img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/599431/127612211/stock-photo-green-apple-isolated-on-white-background-127612211.jpg" width=300 height=150></div>
    <div class="textHolder">some text goes here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated the snippet.. Please try now... I don't have IE9 on my machine so couldn't try it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is stupid but I don't understand why you can't attach this event on the `.imageHolder`?

```js
$('.imageHolder').on('click', function(e) {
  if (window.getSelection.empty) { // Chrome
      window.getSelection().empty();
    } 
  else if (window.getSelection().removeAllRanges) { // Firefox
      window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
  else if (document.selection) { // IE?
    document.selection.empty();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.imageHolder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.textHolder {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="imageHolder">
    <img src="http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/599431/127612211/stock-photo-green-apple-isolated-on-white-background-127612211.jpg" width=300 height=150>
  </div>
  <div class="textHolder">some text goes here</div>
</div>
```